# Updating to Drupal6 on FreeBSD 7: Error Code 1 during make install

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, freebsd, autoconf

I had a working Drupal site and I tried to upgrade my 5.5 version to Drupal6. After trying to update the version from the ports collection:

```
cd /usr/ports/www/drupal6
make install ; make clean
```

I received an error:

```
autoconf: required version 2.68 not found
```

I then went to the ports directory for autoconf and ran: make install ; make clean

Everything installed correctly but when I try to reinstall drupal6 I get the same error message, which is:

```
    => SHA256 Checksum OK for php-5.3.5.tar.bz2.
===>  Patching for php5-gd-5.3.5
===>  Applying FreeBSD patches for php5-gd-5.3.5
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/phpize - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on file: /usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig/xpm.pc - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/autoconf-2.68 - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on shared library: freetype.9 - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on shared library: png.6 - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on shared library: jpeg.11 - found
===>   php5-gd-5.3.5 depends on shared library: t1.5 - found
===>  PHPizing for php5-gd-5.3.5
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
autoconf: required version 2.68 not found
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/graphics/php5-gd.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/drupal6.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/drupal6.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/www/drupal6.
===>  Cleaning for php5-gd-5.3.5
===>  Cleaning for drupal6-6.20
```

My drupal site: [jameshayekserv.com/drupal](http://jameshayekserv.com/drupal)

shows a blank page...

my wordpress site: [jameshayekserv.com/wordpress](http://jameshayekserv.com/wordpress)

tells me:

> Your PHP installation appears to be
>   missing the MySQL extension which is
>   required by WordPress.

I then tried to install the php5 port and get the same exact error as above, autoconf: required version 2.68 not found, although it is installed.

I also tried the command:

```
make config
```

while in the php5 directory. I did not see any options pertaining to MySQL

At one point I got tired of using ports and downloaded Drupal-7.0 from the Drupal site and then scp the file to my server.

I then renamed my /usr/local/www/drupal6 folder to RENAMED_drupal6
Placed the drupal-7.0 folder in the /www directory.
I then changed the drupal.conf file from:

```
jameshayekserv# less /usr/local/etc/apache22/Includes/drupal.conf
Alias /drupal "/usr/local/www/drupal5/"
<Directory "/usr/local/www/drupal5/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to:

```
jameshayekserv# less /usr/local/etc/apache22/Includes/drupal.conf
Alias /drupal "/usr/local/www/drupal-7.0/"
<Directory "/usr/local/www/drupal-7.0/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I then restarted apache:

```
apachectl graceful
```

After thinking I was done I tried to visit my drupal site:

[jameshayekserv.com/drupal](http://jameshayekserv.com/drupal) and was greeted with a blank page.

I can't install from ports after updating, I can't install by placing the folder in the directory and I can't get rid of the "autoconf: required version 2.68 not found" error even though I installed the latest port of autoconf.

I am stuck and down a drupal site with no clue what to do.

Comment: Are you installing Drupal or PHP? There is no reason why you should run autoconf if you are just updating you Drupal version. It looks like you are trying to install a new version of PHP, which is a different question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
cd /usr/ports/devel/autoconf-wrapper && make clean && make deinstall && make reinstall

Threre is a hint in /usr/ports/UPDATING about this:
20101204:
AFFECTS: autotools
AUTHOR: autotools@FreeBSD.org

The next stage in the ongoing cleanup of autotools-using ports is
a refactoring of bsd.autotools.mk so that version numbers are no longer
needed within the USE_AUTOTOOLS stanza. There is either
autoconf213/autoconf or automake14/automake (for the legacy versions,
and the currently available versions). This will considerably reduce
the amount of tree-wide patching in future on an update.

IMPORTANT: if you have either devel/autoconf-wrapper or
devel/automake-wrapper installed on your system (and you most likely do)
PLEASE update these ports to their new versions before updating anything
else -- Bad Things[tm] are likely to happen otherwise.